# Craft paginate not working in merge Queries

Tags: craft3

My Code:

```
{% set Entries              =   craft.entries.section('not loanConsultants').search(searchQuery).orderBy('dateCreated desc').all() %}

{% set loanConsultants      =   craft.entries.section('loanConsultants').type('loanConsultants').search('title:'~searchQuery).orderBy('dateCreated desc').all() %}

{% set Branch               =   craft.entries.section('loanConsultants').type('branches').search('title:'~searchQuery).orderBy('dateCreated desc').all() %}

{% set loanConsultantsMerge = loanConsultants|merge(Branch) %}

{% set mergeResults         = loanConsultantsMerge|merge(Entries) %}
```

Pagination code:

```
{% paginate mergeResults as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
{% for entry in pageEntries %}
    <h5>{{ entry.title }}</h5>
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}" class="btn btn-success" style="color: blue;">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}

{% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}" class="btn btn-success" style="color: blue;">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paginate tag requires an element query to work and by calling `.all()` on your queries, you've turned them into an array of elements.

Something like this should work:

```
{# Grab all of the IDs #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('not loanConsultants').search(searchQuery).ids() %}

{% set loanConsultants = craft.entries.section('loanConsultants').type('loanConsultants').search('title:'~searchQuery).ids() %}

{% set branch =   craft.entries.section('loanConsultants').type('branches').search('title:'~searchQuery).ids() %}

{# Merge the IDs together #}
{% set loanConsultantsMerge = loanConsultants|merge(branch) %}
{% set mergeResults = loanConsultantsMerge|merge(entries) %}

{# Build new query #}
{% set results = craft.entries.id($mergeResults) %}

{% paginate results as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
{% for entry in pageEntries %}
    <h5>{{ entry.title }}</h5>
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}" class="btn btn-success" style="color: blue;">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}

{% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}" class="btn btn-success" style="color: blue;">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```